# Cardinality of this set: $\{n\mid\textrm{$n$ is a natural number and $n^2 < 0$}\}.$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

This is my first time posting. I want to get into computer science as a career and have been following a free online "course". Right now, the math has been killing me, but I'm grinding through it. The textbook I've been using is Discrete Mathematics by Rosen. I'm just learning cardinality of sets and it's been pretty simple and straightforward until now. I was doing my exercises and came across this:

$$
\{n\mid\textrm{$n$ is a natural number and $n^2 < 0$}\}.
$$

I've tried going back in the book to help with my understanding of this, but I'm just not getting it. I've tried searching online and haven't had any luck either. I feel like the answer is something so simple, but it's just not sinking in.

Comment: Can you think of any natural number $n$ such that $n^{2} <0$?

Comment: The set is empty, but the question is, do you understand what you are being asked?

Comment: Remember that $\{n \mid P(n)\}$ is just the set of all naturals numbers such that $P(n)$ is true. In this case, it just happens that $P(n)$ is always false! Don't be thrown off by this. It might as well say "the set of all natural numbers such that $1 = 2$". There are no such numbers, so this set has no elements, ie it is the empty set. The empty set has cardinality $0$ of course!

Answer (score 1):

$$\{n\mid\textrm{$n$ is a natural number and $n^2 < 0$}\}= \emptyset.$$

Answer (score 1):

It completely depends what definition of the natural numbers you are using to really understand what is meant by "the natural numbers"; but intuitively it's all the counting numbers, namely

$${\{1,2,3,4,...\}}$$

Notice we do not include $0$. Most definitions do not, but again this will depend on the definition you follow.

Anyways, regardless of whether $0$ is included or not - the square of any of these numbers will be non-negative. In fact, the only numbers that give negative results when squared are the imaginary numbers. So as others have stated, the set you are referring to

$${\{n\text{ is a natural number }\ |\ n^2<0 \} = \emptyset}$$

Where ${\emptyset}$ denotes the empty set, the set with $0$ elements inside. Hence the cardinality is $0$.